# Xcode, no provisioning profile was found for this executable

Tags: ios, xcode

So I've had this problem before, but I never know the right away to approach it.  I created a new provisoning profile through the Xcode organizer and tried to use that to run on the device.  It did not work.  I got the no valid prov profile error.  When I go to the organizer, I see my profiles are all green.  The iPad I connect to are all green at first, and then near the end of the build process, when Xcode says, "Validating", the circle next to the iPad in the organizer that I'm trying to build on turns yellow, and then I get the error, " a valid provisioning porfiles for this executable was not found."  I have cleaned my build folder, restarted my machine, disconnected and reconnected my devices, nothing works.  This all worked about a week ago.  The only thing that I did since then was upgrade to Xcode 4.5.1.  When I tried to go back using Xcode 4.5, I still get the same error.  I'm not really sure what to look for next.  I watched Apple's video from WWDC 2012 about building, archiving, and submitting your app, but that did not help me fix this issue. Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you skip the part where you grab the profile from your list of provisioning profiles in the organizer and drag it into the device in the devices list?

Comment: Make sure your plist's bundle id matches the one in your provisioning profile for your app.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with I upgraded XCode.  First makes sure that your device is in the provisioning profile.  Somehow mine wasn't even though I am sure it was before.  Then, refresh your certificates from the Organizer in XCode using your credentials.  Then you have to restart xcode, set the code signing identities again and then you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to set the code signing identity in 'Targets' as well as 'Project' after the problem appeared in 4.5.1

Answer (score 0):

One thing we're trying now is a long shot, but it could be your problem as well: if this is a new iPad or device you're using, make sure to register it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your certificates are valid. Go to keychain access and check the certificates there.